# Curl command to C# web rest api request

Tags: c#, rest, curl

I have the following cURL command which works properly to get the data i need and I am trying to call this API from within my C# code.

```
curl "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/senate/RI/current.json" -   H "X-API-Key: <MyAPIKey>"
```

I have written the following code in C# to try calling this API.

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

    static void Main()
    {
        var listing = GetCongressmanByState("IL");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<List<Congressman>> GetCongressmanByState(string State)
    {
        string apiurl = "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/senate/" + State + "/current.json";
        string apikey= "<MyAPIKey>";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-API-Key", apikey);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiurl);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var rootResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
            return rootResult.congressmen;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

Trying to step through the GetCongressmanByState the program seems to jump over my if statements and right back to the main function.

When i run with a breakpoint at console.readline() this is what is within listing: 
[listing contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn5RJ.png)

Is there an issue with my code?

Comment: Your async method returns a task. You aren't doing anything with that task. If you did `List<Congressman> congressmanList = listing.Result;` then that should get you the answer you want. Accessing `.Result` will basically cause the task to be executed. There may be better ways to do it but I'm not much of an expert with async code.

Comment: Made that change and looks like the result is null. Checked the reponse and im getting a 403 forbidden message. Am i assigning the header portion of the curl command improperly in the C# code?

Comment: Solved it! Integrated the header section like this:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Key", apikey);